# Replicating preloaded HTML /DOM method results in an array using AJAX/PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, dom

I have a function that creates an array that contains the return value from the HTML DOM method : window.document.getElementById()

```
function makearray1(){
  var array1=[1,window.document.getElementById('divID'),['a','b'],[1,2]];
  }
```

then I pass the array into another function

```
use(array1)

function use(xxx){
   xxx[1].innerHTML=xxx[2][0];
   }
```

and 'a' is written in the appropriate div

---

later I decided to put the array in a form and post it to a txt file on the server using php and:

```
JSON.stringify(array)
```

---

So now I use AJAX to call the data from the txt file after the rest of the page has loaded etc... and the original function used to make the array is not included at all.

so my php is basically this:

```
 $a1='use(';
 $data1 =file_get_contents("text_file.txt") ;
 $a2=')';

 echo $a1.$data1.$a2;
```

and the response text:

```
 var n= XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
 eval(n);
```

which pretty much means this:

```
 use(text_file)

 function use(xxx){
   xxx[1].innerHTML=xxx[2][0];
   }
```

---

the problem is that the array in the text file looks like this:

```
   [1,null,['a','b'],[1,2]]
```

instead of:

```
   [1,window.document.getElementById('divID'),['a','b'],[1,2]]
```

---

My question: Is there any way that I can do the equivalent of what I'm trying to do here, which is immediately replicate the return value of the HTML/DOM method in an array using AJAX/php?

To clarify: this is a simple example. I actually have a huge, multidimensional array that already has established pointers, or prefetched DOM nodes in it. Now I'm trying to replicate the array when a text version is loaded using ajax. I'm looking for a recursive approach to changing all of the null assignments with something that will immediately fetch the appropriate DOM node. Most likely I will need to do it with the response text, but was hoping I could do it with the php portion.

Comment: _"I have a function that creates an array that contains the HTML DOM method: `window.document.getElementById()`"_ - No you don't. You create an array that contains the return value from `getElementById()`, which will either be a reference to a specific DOM element or `null` if no element has the specified id. And a DOM element won't be stringified.

Comment: you should pass window.document.getElementById('divID').innerHTML instead of window.document.getElementById('divID')

Comment: so I'm looking to replicate the return value in the array as soon as I load the array into the page

Comment: this is a simplified example, passing window.document.getElementById('divID').innerHTML instead of window.document.getElementById('divID') doesn't help me

Comment: just save the **ID** in the array, and do `getElementById` by that id instead of prefetching the DOM node and passing it...

Comment: so I'm trying to prefetch the DOM node and place it in the array as soon as it loads onto the page

Comment: pretty sure the only way you can serialize a dom node is with innerHTML, in this incredible new format called HTML

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to stringify a reference to a javascript object in the memory of whatever computer is evaluating getElementById first, and that has no chance to represent something on the end client's computer.

Send the id instead:

```
function makearray1(){
  array1=[1,'divID',['a','b'],[1,2]];
  }
```

then, in the client:

```
function use(xxx){
   window.document.getElementById(xxx[1]).innerHTML=xxx[2][0];
   }
```

If you really want to eval it at the end,  you can use this, I guess

```
function makearray1(){
  array1=[1,"window.document.getElementById(\"divID\")",['a','b'],[1,2]];
  }
```

I've no idea why you would want to do that though

Comment: I wasn't under the illusion that stringify was going to work. I was looking for a way to replicate what the original array looked like after the fact without adding another function that makes an array. Thanks for your very bland imagination.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the dom element exists in the second page, it should look something like this.

JS:

```
function packDomData(){
  return {
          "MySpecificYetBriefProperty0":1,
          "DomID":"divID",
          "MySpecificYetBriefProperty1":['a','b'],
          "MySpecificYetBriefProperty2":[1,2]
      };
}
function useDomData(domData){
   document.getElementByID(domData.DomID).innerHTML=domData.MySpecificYetBriefProperty1[0];
}
```

PHP:

```
//Make sure the contents of this file is the json from packDomData. use json_encode in php or JSON.stringify in js
echo file_get_contents("text_file.txt");

var myData = JSON.parse(XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText);
useDomData(myData);
```

I used to code like you. Here are some tips that have helped turn my coding horror into a fun job:

- Use objects with descriptive properties instead of arrays whenever you aren't actually looping through the array - I promise it will save you and others headache! "DomID" is much more flexible than 1, and if you change the order in the array, javascript gods help you that array is everywhere - including however many random text files on your server!
- Also use descriptive names for functions
- Always return a value from a function instead of using globals whenever possible, even where the result is then used as a nasty global. Trust me.
- Never put javascript function names in an ajax call. Use JSON instead and keep the functions and other script in the javascript file where it belongs.
- Mysql will save your life!!

Disclaimer - I didn't run this code but it should basically work when you get everything hooked up right.

Comment: thanks for your advice! javascript function names in an ajax call? did I do that here?

Comment: In the PHP response: **`$a1='use(';** and then it is run with **eval**. It means that your PHP has to be maintained very closely with your javascript, and makes your ajax code less portable. Using JSON.parse and then passing those values to the appropriate function in JS is cleaner.

Comment: After reading your edit, what you need is still a function on the javascript end, no way to do it PHP alone. It would recurse through your response objesct/array and look for DOM selectors, like '#MyID', and replace them with DomNodes. There are a couble of libraries that do something similar. One in particular made it appear as though all of your selection was indeed occurring on the php side, and it quietly handled all the javascript. I haven't used it myself but it's called xajax: [link]http://www.xajax-project.org/ Does any of that help? If you want more specific examples of recursing ask.